# Reading binary file in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, binaryfiles

I need to extract data from a binary file.

I used `binaryRecords` and get `RDD[Array[Byte]]`.

From here I want to parse every record into
`case class (Field1: Int, Filed2 : Short, Field3: Long)`

How can I do this?

Comment: do you have a delimiter in the binary file?

Comment: No, no delimiter. Regular binary file built by C program with the structure int, short, long

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming you have no delimiter, an Int in Scala is 4 bytes, Short is 2 byte and long is 8 bytes. Assume that your Binary data was structured (for each line) as Int Short Long. You should be able to take the bytes and convert them to the classes you want.

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer

val result = YourRDD.map(x=>(ByteBuffer.wrap(x.take(4)).getInt,
             ByteBuffer.wrap(x.drop(4).take(2)).getShort,
             ByteBuffer.wrap(x.drop(6)).getLong))
```

This uses a Java library to convert Bytes to Int/Short/Long, you can use other libraries if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Since Spark 3.0, Spark has a “binaryFile” data source to read Binary file

I've found this at [How to read Binary file into DataFrame](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-read-binary-file-into-dataframe/) with more explanation.

```
val df = spark.read.format("binaryFile").load("/tmp/binary/spark.png")
  df.printSchema()
  df.show()
```

This outputs schema and DataFrame as below

```
root
 |-- path: string (nullable = true)
 |-- modificationTime: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- length: long (nullable = true)
 |-- content: binary (nullable = true)

+--------------------+--------------------+------+--------------------+
|                path|    modificationTime|length|             content|
+--------------------+--------------------+------+--------------------+
|file:/C:/tmp/bina...|2020-07-25 10:11:...| 74675|[89 50 4E 47 0D 0...|
+--------------------+--------------------+------+--------------------+
```

Thanks