# Spark, how to read a file as byte array?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is there a way to read a file as byte array in spark?

As of now I am using the below code, but the content of the file changing in byte level. Its an encrypted file, so looking for ways to read the file without any change in byte level. I see lot of question on the same topic, but none provide a satisfactory answer. So posting this question as it could help other also. Thanks

```
val rawFileRDDEncrypted = spark.sparkContext.textFile("path")
```

Comment: No it doesn't resolve my question. I am trying to read only one ecrypted file as byte array

Comment: does sc.binaryFiles() work?

Comment: sc.binaryFile is what refered in the link you shared above and it didnt work

Comment: why it didn't work? The [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.2/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.binaryFiles) says it will read as a byte array.

Comment: spark.sparkContext.binaryFiles("path") this is what I tried and I couldnt get the bytes out of it. If you have snippets can you share ... thanks

Comment: You should be able to use `spark.read.format("binaryFile").load("path")` if you use Spark 3.0+, see:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63743089/7579547

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Made it work with this

```
val binaryFileList = spark.sparkContext.binaryFiles("file").collect()
val byteArray: Array[Array[Byte]] = binaryFileList.map(tuple=> {
  val pds = tuple._2
  val dis = pds.open()
  val len = dis.available();
  val buf = Array.ofDim[Byte](len)
  pds.open().readFully(buf)
  buf
})
```